# Where should I look to find out what cause my server hang?

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-vcenter

I just had a Windows 2012 R2 guest on ESXi 5.5 stop responding. Resetting the machine from the vsphere client worked. Restarting the machine from there resulted in a message saying something like "VMware tools not installed". Vcenter was giving error messages after the problems started, this might have something to do with the windows guest being the file server containing all the profiles and redirections.

After restarting the windows machine in the above manner, everything is running fine. Logs show nothing apart from the unexpected restart, no errors beforehand. I saw no weird usage patterns for this server in vcenter either. I do want to know what was the cause though. Where should I look?

The setup is a single host running VMware ESXi 5.5 running several guests including the problematic Windows 2012 R2 guest and the vcenter virtual appliance.

Comment: Do you have the VMware guest tools installed in the virtual machine? If not, that would be step one.

Comment: `Restarting the machine from there resulted in a message saying something like "VMware tools not installed". Vcenter was giving error messages after the problems started` - It would be really helpful to know what the messages actually said.

Comment: The VMware guest tools are installed in the VM. The message from vCenter were (in the webclient) along the line of "vCenter encountered a problem, do you want to continue or reload". I'll check if I can recover the error messages.